# How can I copy the input content to webpage source for HTML5 video player?

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

Hy!
I working on a video player, and I would like to make a preview secticon for player.
Looks like this:

```
<input type="url" ontype="" id="videourl" placeholder="Give the mp4 URL here">
<input type="url" ontype="" id="video poster" placeholder="Give here the video poster" >
```

And here come the video player which based on video.js.

You see the "ontype" section.
Here comes the functions, which can show the player for user.
And if you typed correctly datas, the player work and you get the video poster and the video (and of course you can play).

The player strukture:

```
<video id="vid3" controls preload="none" poster="Here come the input value" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["flash"] }'>
    <source src="Here come the input value" id="iframe_field" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Comment: What is `ontype` supposed to do?

Comment: When you typped, the player get the video or poster depends which input typed.

Comment: So what you mean is, you type an url to a video in the input, and then it opens that video URL in the `<video>` element?

Comment: I edited my quetion, I hope now cleard.

Otherwise:
You typed the video URL and this data come to the source src, and the video show immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this HTML:

```
<input type="url" id="videourl" placeholder="Give the mp4 URL here" value="">
<input type="url" id="videoposter" placeholder="Give here the video poster" value="">
<button onclick="reload();">Load Video</button>

<video id="vid3" controls preload="none" poster="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
    <source src="" id="iframe_field" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

...and this JS:

```
function reload() {
    var videourl = $('#videourl')[0].value;
    var videoposter = $('#videoposter')[0].value;
    $('#vid3').attr('poster', videoposter);
    $('#vid3').attr('src', videourl);
    videojs("vid3", {}, function(){
        this.load();
    });
}
```

(jQuery and video.js required.)

[Jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/meyudeka/1/edit).

Does the above do what you want? I don't know what the "ontype" attribute in the input elements is for.

Comment: Yeah, that's better solution, thanks!
Wpould be nice if this happend on key up, but now I have something, so thank you very much! :D

Comment: Well, I tryed video.js player and dosen't want work, and I don't know why.
Here the site:
http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/HTML_generator/index.html
On bottom, you can see the player.
Filds:
The first fild is the video source, the second is the video poster.

Comment: I tried that page. Entered a video URL in first field, and a poster URL in second field, clicked Generate and it downloaded an HTML file with an embedded video. I loaded that file in my browser and the video I chose played fine.

Comment: The file is working, of course, but the preview player dosen't.
This script need for them.
Just I wouldlike make a preview, before you download the file.

Comment: I maked a jsbin demo with your script and the player.
http://jsbin.com/meyudeka/2/edit
Please review it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this HTML code:

```
<form action="javascript:loadVideo()">
    <input type="url" id="source" />
    <input type="url" id="poster" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<video id="vid3" controls src=""></video>
```

with the following JavaScript code:

```
function loadVideo() {
    var vid = document.getElementById('vid3');
    vid.src = document.getElementById('source').value;
    vid.poster = document.getElementById('poster').value;
}
```

Try [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2JEqx/1/), which already has a video URL filled in for the input, which was taken from [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html).

That will load the video into the `<video>` element when the user presses enter, or clicks the button to submit.

Comment: That is because you forgot to remove the `onLoad` in the jsFiddle. You need to select "No wrap - in <head>", otherwise it won't work. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9spyx/1/) fixed version of your fiddle. The only thing I changed is the dropdown to the left of the HTML code.

Comment: Can you add poster atribute?
The poster atibute is the first picture for the player.

Comment: Here a reference for html5 poster :)
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_poster

Comment: The user would then manually have to enter the poster URL. But, sure, you could simply add another input that would allow the user to enter an URL for the poster: http://jsfiddle.net/2JEqx/1/. I've updated my answer to include those.

Comment: The player is stacked.
But the @bloodyKnuckles solution is good!
Thanks for your work!